# find an elementary matrix $E$ such that $EA=B$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

and

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

Find an elementary matrix $E$ such that $EA= B$.

I try with many

$$E = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

but not correct

Comment: Did you guess your $E$ or do you have a method?

Comment: I guess it , I don't have a method

Comment: Do you know how to transform $A$ in $B$ using elementary *row*-operations?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elementary matrix is one which differs from the identity matrix by one elementary row operation.

Note that $B$ is the matrix $A$ with three times the first row added to the second. So if we take the matrix

$$E=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

and now consider

$$EA=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}=B$$

$E$ was the identity matrix with three times the first row added to the second. This is easy to figure out because the matrix $B$ is linear combinations of the rows of $A$ and linear combinations of the columns of $E$.